# change color of a lightning-vertical-navigation-item-icon

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components, lightning-experience, css, lightning-design-system

I am building an lwc menu and have a

```
<lightning-vertical-navigation-item-icon
  label="Sessions"
  name="sessions"
  icon-name="utility:event"
  class="myIcon"
>
</lightning-vertical-navigation-item-icon>
```

But cant seem to change the color I think I tried everything with my CSS to override the default color but doesn't work

```
.slds-icon,
.slds-icon-text-default,
.slds-icon_x-small,
.my-icon,
lightning-primitive-icon,
.slds-nav-vertical__action {
  fill: #fff !important;
  color: #fff !important;
  background-color: #fff !important;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could achieve this with [styling hooks](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/platforms/lightning/styling-hooks/).
In the chrome console you can see that for filling color is used this variable `--sds-c-icon-color-foreground-default`.

[image]

You can override this variable with any color you want, as follows.

yourComponent.css

```
:host {
    --sds-c-icon-color-foreground-default: green;
}
```

Comment: intresting. But i get this error when i vscode try to compile it "CssSyntaxError: LWC1009: postcss-plugin-lwc: 15:3: Invalid definition of custom property "--sds-c-icon-color-foreground-default"."

Comment: update pushing the code to the scratch org works there is a [bug](https://issueexplorer.com/issue/forcedotcom/lwc-dev-server-feedback/92) thats associated with styling hook not working in the dev server

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be two-fold,

Your css is targeting

```
Classes:

 - my-icon
 - slds-nav-vertical__action

HTML Tags:
 - lightning-primitive-icon
```

Whereas your HTML is slightly mismatching the CSS provided

```
Classes:
 - myIcon

HTML Tag:
 - lightning-vertical-navigation-item-icon
```

If you rename your CSS target to look for `.myIcon` rather than `.my-icon` you should get success

Alternative Approach:
Rather than use CSS `color` and `background-color`. Use `filter` for the SVG.

White would be `filter: invert(96%) sepia(0%) saturate(0%) hue-rotate(121deg) brightness(104%) contrast(105%);` You can use [codepen.io/sosuke/pen/Pjoqqp](http://codepen.io/sosuke/pen/Pjoqqp) to convert HEX to Filter

Comment: Thanks for catching the typo; but changing the HTML element to lightning-vertical-navigation-item-icon just changes the background color not the icon itself

Comment: I definitely recommend using the SLDS Styling hooks! But I also know it's an SVG which is a pain to colour. Rather than use `color` or `background-color`. An option would be to use `filter`. For instance: White would be `filter: invert(96%) sepia(0%) saturate(0%) hue-rotate(121deg) brightness(104%) contrast(105%);` You can use https://codepen.io/sosuke/pen/Pjoqqp to convert HEX to Filter

Comment: -mindblown. I probably would use this hack as styling hooks don't work on my dev server. If you edit your answer to include the filter I can accept it as an answer too

Comment: @dovigz Updated! It's definitely a circumstance based hacky approach but glad it works!